# How to install node_rrd correctly?

Tags: node.js, meteor, rrdtool, rrd

If I ask this here it's because I'm using MeteorJS and I need to use RRD. I founded a node_rrd that do all I need to do right [here](https://github.com/Orion98MC/node_rrd).

The problem is that I have installed all these things in my terminal:

```
 brew install rrdtool  
 meteor npm install rrd  
 meteor npm install rrdtool
 meteor npm install node-rrdtool
```

I did the following install to because in [dependencies](https://github.com/Orion98MC/node_rrd#dependencies) they say that I need to do :

```
 meteor npm install -g node-gyp
```

And when I do a `console.log(rrd)`I have this:

```
 { RRD: { [Function: RRD] restore: [Function] } }
```

But when I want to create the file as in the [basic usage](https://github.com/Orion98MC/node_rrd#basic-usage) I have an errro `rrd.create is not a function`

So my question is someone here has already worked with RRD on nodeJS ? Or Someone know how to install node_rrd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the instructions for RRD on the github page you will see this:

> **Using git**
>
> ```
> $ git clone <this repository>
> $ cd node_rrd
> $ npm install .
> ```

Basically you need to download the repo to your local machine and build it. You are on the right track with setting up gyp, but don't use `meteor npm` for that, it needs to be global for your computer, so do this:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

The `sudo` is optional I think if you are on Windows. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: I have cloned the repo on my desktop then did the install but it looks like I still can't use the method of `node_rrd` so I'll check with somebody at work. I mark your answer as the right one because it's exactly what I need to do to install `node_rrd`